# Check if asterisk exists in a string

Tags: php

I have to check if an asterisk exists in the string, but it always shows that there is no asterisk.

Why does `strpos()` not work? I have also tried `stripos()`, `mb_strpos()`, and `mb_stripos()` without luck.

```
<?php

$str = "****123";
if(strpos($str, '*') == false){
    echo 'There is no asterisk in the string';  
} else {
    echo 'There is asterisk in the string';     
}
```

#### Desired output:

There is no asterisk in the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) returns an integer (0 or more) or `FALSE` if not found. In PHP, [the comparison](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) with `0` and `FALSE` are different only if you use a strict equality (`===`):

```
$str = "****123";
if(strpos($str, '*') === false){
    echo 'There is no asterisk in the string';  
} else {
    echo 'There is asterisk in the string';     
}
```

Outputs:

*There is asterisk in the string*

Answer (score 0):

```
if (substr('*abcdef', 0, 1) === '*') { ... }
```